# Basic json output to file in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have the following logstash config

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/log"
    type => "tomcat"
    start_position => "beginning"
    
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^P50\s+:\s+[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,2}\s+[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}


filter {
   if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      drop { }
   }
  grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:details}" }
  }
  mutate {
        remove_field =>  [ "%{@version}", "%{type}", "%{@host}", "%{log}", "%{@timestamp}" ]  
  }
}

output {
   file {
      path => "/out.log"
      file_mode => 0644
      codec => line { format => "{timestamp:%{timestamp},level:%{level},details:%{details}}" }
   }
}
```

So in the output file I want json with these 3 fields (that are added in the grok filter)

```
{"timestamp": "...", "level":"...", "details": "..."},
{"timestamp": "...", "level":"...", "details": "..."},
...
```

I want to remove all other fields.

Somehow however I also get the fields `[ "%{@version}", "%{type}", "%{@host}", "%{log}", "%{@timestamp}" ]`  that I am removing in the mutate.

I am probably missing something on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prune filter to remove fields. The [@timestamp] field is not removed by default. Your test for the _grokparsefailure tag will never do anything, because it is testing for the presence of the tag before the grok filter has a chance to add it. Move the

```
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] { drop { } }
```

to be after the grok. Then use

```
prune {
    whitelist_names => [ "timestamp", "level", "details" ] 
    remove_field => "@timestamp"
}
```

for the output, use a json_lines codec.